# how to run a script on server using fastApi

Tags: python, api, fastapi

i'm new to fastAPI
imported a script into the main.py in my fastAPI based api

```
import example
```

how to run the script when calling the url with value in the script

like http://127.0.0.1:8000/url=https://google.com

to make the script waiting for the value after "url="

Comment: Possible `?` symbol missing in query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/{param}")
async def read_user_item(param: str, url: str):
    item = {"param": param, "url": url}
    return item
```

**http://127.0.0.1:8000/index?url=https://google.com**

for this output will

**{"param":"index","url":"https://google.com"}**

> Hope this will help you as well.
> https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/